# How to execute a jbpm business process from a workitem handler

Tags: jbpm

In business process A we're using a task which executes a workitem handler which executes business process B.
Whenever we try to use events in business process B (e.g. timer), the process waits forever.
Thanks,
Eliezer

Comment: Can you share workItemHandler code you are using to call another BPMN process? By default jbpm engine uses singleton runtime strategy, try using PerProcessInstance runtime strategy.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the code. We're not using the singleton runtime strategy, and we discovered that jBPM waits for all synchronous tasks to end before it starts the asynchronous task (e.g. timer event). Therefore, the process waits until we complete the execute method of the workitem handler, before it continues to handle timer event. To overcome this, we tried to register for the end event of process B, but this registration is lost somewhere along the way

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

1. a async execution of your workitemhandler code. More details on this here on the offical webpage: https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.3.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_asynchronous_execution
2. return a variable with your workitemhandler that is User in the process model to run a Subprocess-call.